# How can I do continuous build/unit testing in Coffeescript?

Tags: coffeescript

I'm writing a (ever larger) set of unit tests using Coffeescript and node.js.  I build the files using the coffee "watch" option (-w)

```
coffee -w -b -c -o web/ src/
```

My problem is that running the unit tests takes 20 secs (I'm assuming for the compile to .js).

If possible, I'd like automatically run the unit tests on a (compiled .js) file change, which would eliminate the long wait for the results.

My current Cakefile:

```
fs            = require 'fs'
{print}       = require 'sys'
{spawn, exec} = require 'child_process'

build = (watch, callback) ->
  if typeof watch is 'function'
    callback = watch
    watch = false
  options = ['-c', '-b', '-o', 'web', 'src']
  options.unshift '-w' if watch

  coffee = spawn 'coffee', options
  coffee.stdout.on 'data', (data) -> print data.toString()
  coffee.stderr.on 'data', (data) -> print data.toString()
  coffee.on 'exit', (status) -> callback?() if status is 0

task 'test', 'Run the test suite', ->
  build ->
    require.paths.unshift __dirname + "/lib"
    {reporters} = require 'nodeunit'
    process.chdir __dirname
    reporters.default.run ['test']
```

Comment: Whoa—20 seconds? I've never had a CoffeeScript project that takes that long to compile. Or even 2 seconds, for that matter. Could you try compiling each of your `.coffee` files and see which (if any) are taking more than 1s to compile? Then post a report to the [issue tracker](https://github.com/jashkenas/coffee-script/issues).

Comment: It's probably not the compile--maybe it's node.js overhead?  I'm loading 8 or so requires.  The test itself seems to execute in about ~300ms.

Comment: You mean you're loading 8 or so `require`s in the tests? Could you try timing each of them to see which is taking more than a few milliseconds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the Cakefile for my connect-assets project: https://github.com/adunkman/connect-assets/blob/master/Cakefile

It's a bit more complex than sstephenson's (which I assume your example is derived from), but it shows how you can watch a directory of files for changes and respond to those changes by re-running tests.

Comment: After sorting out a node.js issue (moving from 0.4.12->0.6.4), I'm  getting some errors running your Cakefile:

`execvp(): No such file or directory
 (node) warning: possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 listeners added. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit.
 Trace: 
     at WatchitEmitter.<anonymous> (events.js:133:17)
     at /Users/chambery/node_modules/watchit/lib/watchit.js:35:13
     at Object.oncomplete (/Users/chambery/node_modules/watchit/lib/watchit.js:141:21)
 FATAL ERROR: v8::HandleScope::Close() Local scope has already been closed`      Is this a version issue?

Comment: Hmm. If you can create a test case to replicate this, please post this as a bug report on the [watchit issue tracker](https://github.com/TrevorBurnham/watchit/issues).

Comment: Your Cakefile does the trick. I still can't get it to run the test completely, but the FATAL ERROR is due to a linker error(?) caused the by node upgrade: http://groups.google.com/group/nodejs/browse_thread/thread/877ff6e7434826dd